# Actionbarcompat shows appicon in Android 2.3

Tags: android

By default action bar shows the app icon. To change this, I have added the following in the style.xml

```
<item name="android:icon">@drawable/logo</item>
```

This works perfectly for Android 4.x but for Android but the Android 2.x still show the app icon.
PS. I am using appcompat for backporting  ActionBar

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to declare a logo in the `androidmanifest` with the following line:

```
<application
   ....
   android:logo="@drawable/some_icon">
</application>
```